Involution in simple algebras
Let $(K,\bar{})$ be a field with involution, $D$ be a division $K$-algebra, and $A\cong \text{Mat}_n(D)$ be a simple $K$-algebra with centre $L$.
Suppose $L=K$. In this case, we know if $A$ admits $(K,\bar{}_K)$-involution $*$, then so does $D$ such that $(A,*)\cong \text{Mat}_n\big((D,*)\big)$.
Can we extend this result to the case where $L \ne K$?
Here, we can say if $A$ admits $(L,\bar{}_L)$-involution $\sigma$, then so does $D$ such that $(A,\sigma)\cong \text{Mat}_n\big((D,\sigma)\big)$. Now, if $\bar{}_L\bigg|_K=\bar{}_K$ and $A$ admits $(K,\bar{}_K)$-involution $*$, then can we say $D$ admits the same involution such that $(A,*)\cong \text{Mat}_n\big((D,*)\big)$ ?

Does $\operatorname{Mat}_n((D, \sigma))$ mean that the involution is just to apply $\sigma$ to each entry, or is it, say, $\sigma$-transpose?

I mean $\sigma$-transpose.
